# what is the dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The dimension of the row space of a $8\times 8$ matrix $A$ is 5.if $\mathbb{R}^{8\times 10}$ is a vector space of $8 \times 10$ matrices with real entries.

Then
$S_{A} = \{ B \in \mathbb{R}^{8\times 10} ; AB=0 \}.$ Then dimension of $S_A$

My claim : If we consider $A$ as a $8 \times 8$ matrix with a  $5 \times 5$ identity block matrix in it. and B is any $8\times 10$ matrix. If we multiply both we will get all zero rows correspoding to the non - zero rows of A. The remaining will be a  $3 \times 10$ matrix which can take any values.

So the dimension must be 30. But its displayed that dimension is 40.

Help me out.

Comment: I agree with you.  The nullspace of $A$ is three dimensional, so every column of B lies within the three-dimensional set

Answer (score 1):

You can think to the elements of $S_A$ as $10$-tuples of vectors in the null space of $A$. Since the rank of $A$ is $5$, its null space has dimension $3$, so you have dimension $3\cdot10=30$.

The book is wrong.